# How to determine the Remaining Email in apex

Tags: apex, email, governorlimits, limits

```
Integer email_left = Limits.getEmailInvocations();
system.Debug('Used Email: '+email_left);
Integer emailLimit = Limits.getLimitEmailInvocations();
system.Debug('Email Limit: '+emailLimit);
```

I got the following code but the `email_left` always ouput 0. Even there is no Gorvernor's Limit on email. And `emailLimit` always output 10.

I want to know how many email used, or any functions to know the remaining email. So that i can create a condition:

```
if(remaining != 0){
   //Send Email
}else{
   //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the per-transaction limit, not the global daily limit on sends. `Limits.getEmailInvocations` returns the number of calls (not total emails sent) in the current context, and `Limits.getLimitEmailInvocations` shows the *maximum* number of calls you can use (10) in the current transaction. The amount remaining is the difference between the two (limit-used).

See [reserveMassEmailCapcity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm#apex_System_Messaging_reserveMassEmailCapacity) and the related [reserveSingleEmailCapacity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm#apex_System_Messaging_reserveSingleEmailCapacity) to tell if your transaction will fail if you attempt to send the specified number of messages.